# How to change name of connection in ipconfig

Tags: windows, router, adapter, ipconfig

I typed in my cmd `ipconfig /all`, one of the items I recieved was:

```
Wireless LAN adapter ‏‏חיבור מקומי* 13:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

How do I change the name in the first line, I'm having problems with it because it's in hebrew, but every name change I tried didn't affect what i get from ipconfig.

Answer (score 1):

An adapter name can be changed with the `netsh` command in Windows. Try using:

```
netsh interface set interface name="old name" newname="Your new name"
```

More information can be found on the [technet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/01/14/renaming-network-adapters-by-using-powershell/), including a couple of other ways, including using the Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for commenting on an old post but sometimes the adapter name can be messed up so the other solution can fail.

A fix without using the command prompt is to go to:

Control panel --> Network and Sharing Center --> Change adapter settings --> Rename on the target adapter, **be sure to DELETE the whole old name** before writing a new one